# IsPressed event not triggering in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, button

I'm trying to edit the default template of a button for a WPF application,the "MouseEnter" and "MouseLeave" events are working,the problem is with the "IsPressed" event that basically seems to not be triggered.I also removed the

```
RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
```

part but the button just seems to ignore my IsPressed event
Here's the code:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonDark1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="0.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, we have a question where someone has messed up their `ControlTemplate` and wants someone else to fix it. The answer is always the same... *start with the default `ControlTemplate` for your `Button`*. You can find the default `ControlTemplate` for your `Button` in the [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

If you look at the linked page, you'll see a `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` collection and inside that collection, you'll find a `VisualState` named `Pressed`. A little further up, you should see this:

```
<VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed" />
```

These are what manage the visual `Pressed` state.

When altering a default `ControlTemplate`, it is best to start with the whole default XAML and first get that working in your custom `ControlTemplate`. Once you have it working, *then* you can start to manipulate it, bit by bit and regularly checking it after every few changes. Then, if it doesn't work one time, you can just undo the last few changes and find out what you did wrong.

Comment: Sorry,i'm new to WPF,i'll start with the default template as you said instead of editing the existing one,hopefully this will get fixed,thanks.

Comment: Perfect,this worked,started from the default template it showed me that i was assigning the property in the event in the wrong way.
I used one of the default brush changing the colors and not it works.
Thanks.